# ReactJS: 'type is undefined' when loading a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm fleshing out a website for the first time using ReactJS and React Router. For some reason this component (and it's sister component PageFooter which just has different HTML) are producing the following error:

> Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null or undefined. It
>   should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite
>   components).
>
> Warning: Only functions or strings can be mounted as React components.
>
> TypeError: type is undefined

Here is the code for the component in question:

```
// External dependencies.
var React = require('react');
var ReactRouter = require('react-router');
var Router = ReactRouter.Router;
var Link = Router.Link;

// Define the component
var PageHeader = React.createClass( {

render: function() {
    return (
        <div className="header-wrapper">
            <header className="site-header container" role="banner">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col sm12">
                        <Link to="/" className="identity" rel="home">DTG</Link>
                        <nav id="site-navigation" className="site-navigation" role="navigation" aria-labelledby="menu-heading">
                            <h4 id="menu-heading" className="sr-only">Menu</h4>
                            <button className="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false">
                                <svg width="1792" height="1792" viewBox="0 0 1792 1792" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                    <path d="M1664 1344v128q0 26-19 45t-45 19h-1408q-26 0-45-19t-19-45v-128q0-26 19-45t45-19h1408q26 0 45 19t19 45zm0-512v128q0 26-19 45t-45 19h-1408q-26 0-45-19t-19-45v-128q0-26 19-45t45-19h1408q26 0 45 19t19 45zm0-512v128q0 26-19 45t-45 19h-1408q-26 0-45-19t-19-45v-128q0-26 19-45t45-19h1408q26 0 45 19t19 45z" fill="#fff" />
                                </svg><span>Menu</span>
                            </button>
                            <ul className="menu">
                                <li><Link to="/" activeClassName="active" rel="home">Home</Link></li>
                                <li><Link to="/about" activeClassName="active">About</Link></li>
                                <li><Link to="/blog" activeClassName="active">Blog</Link></li>
                                <li><Link to="/work" activeClassName="active">Work</Link></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
        </div>
    );
  }
} );

module.exports = PageHeader;
```

This code checks out on JSXhint.com, which is even more puzzling.

To confirm, the module containing this component is definitely being loaded. I have a feeling I've missed something obvious, so I'm stepping away from it and throwing it out there!

Are these issues actually to do with the component, or is it something I've not done in React Router?

EDIT: The component is rendered by the parent component `Page`

```
// External dependencies.
var React = require('react');

// Internal dependencies.
var PageHeader  = require( './header' );
var PageFooter  = require( './footer' );

// Define our component.
var Page = React.createClass( {

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <PageHeader/>
                <PageFooter/>
            </div>
        );
    }
} );

module.exports = Page;
```

Comment: can you show us where the component is rendered?

Comment: @gapvision Just updated the question to include the parent component!

Comment: and it's working when you remove `PageHeader` and/or `PageFooter`? Just to be sure....

Comment: tried running this with react-router v0.13.3.. `ReactRouter.Router` seems to be undefined... using `require('/react-router/lib/Router')`  directly like in the example on their github page doesnt work either.

from personal experience, that error usually shows up when one of your components is `undefined` or `null`

Comment: @yash I'm on the 1.0.X release at the moment.

Comment: @gapvision I've just been through the markup, gradually adding more and more elements as I go and as soon as the first <Link> appears, the error comes up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

react-router's documentation is a little outdated... You should use the following to require `Link` for version 0.13.x:

```
var ReactRouter = require('react-router');
var Link = ReactRouter.Link;
```

I don't recommend using v1.0.0-rc1 since it's not production ready.. Either way, you should require `Link` component like above in this version as well :)

Answer (score 1):

After some further debugging, it would seem that the issues lie with my use of...

`var Link = Router.Link;`

...when it should be...

`var Link = ReactRouter.Link;`